# Is $R(\gcd_{i\in I} x_i) = \sum_{i\in I} Rx_i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of elements with a greatest common divisor.

> Is $R(\gcd_{i\in I} x_i) = \sum_{i\in I} Rx_i$?

Here, the RHS is the smallest ideal containing $Rx_i$ for all $i\in I$.

Of course, $R(\gcd_{i\in I} x_i) \supseteq \sum_{i\in I} Rx_i$, since $x\mid y \Rightarrow Ry\subseteq Rx$.

I don't even know, whether this is true for PID's or in fact $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true in PIDs, but not in UFDs. For instance in $R=k[X,Y]$, $k$ a field, then $X$ and $Y$ have gcd $1$ but $RX+RY\ne R1$ (indeed $RX+RY$ is not principal).

Infinite sums are no problem in PIDs, since a PID is always Noetherian.